# Oracle SQL Check if a date field falls within a certain range

Tags: sql, oracle

I need to pull all of the qualifying insurance events in our system that happen over the previous week.  I am using the below code but it is definitely off as it is pulling some events that happened as far back as the summer.  It seems that it is going back months instead of seven days.  I appreciate any advice/help!  Thank you!

```
SELECT *
FROM EMPLOYEE_LIFE_EVENTS
WHERE LIFE_EVENT_DATE >= (sysdate - 7)
ORDER BY LIFE_EVENT_DATE DESC
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: `sysdate - 7` does give you the current date/time minus 7 days, as you expect. The problem probably lies in your data, so you should build a minimal reproducible example that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Include the data type as well - just in case `LIFE_EVENT_DATE` isn't actually a date and you are doing a string comparison.

Comment: The data was being stored in the table as a string.  I ran a TO_DATE function on the data and it worked out.  Thank you!

Comment: Storing dates as strings is a bad idea ([see here, for example](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:77598210939534). You should rethink your data model.